# CollisionShape2d attaching to Bone2d

Tags: godot

I'm working on a 2d godot project and I made my character with skeleton and bones properly. But I want to add a collisionShape/Polygon2d for  each body parts of character and attach it to its suitable bone to move  with that. But I don't know how.
thanks

Comment: See [2D skeletons](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/animation/2d_skeletons.html).

Comment: What is it? I'd read it before. there was nothing.

Comment: Well, if that is not what you need… Either you want the skeleton to drive physics, you want physics to drive the skeleton, or both. For the skeleton to drive physics, you can attach physic bodies as children of the bones. For physics to drive the skeleton, you  ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶d̶r̶a̶g̶d̶o̶l̶l̶ ̶i̶t̶ actually there is no ragdoll support in 2D :( - You would have to make the skeleton with RigidBody2D and Joint2D, and then have them control the bones. And both at the same time gets complicated, I don't have a good solution for that.